# mysql query for average bookings per month

Tags: mysql

I am working on a query to give me a view of customer habits, eg - average spend, number of bookings etc.

my current query looks like

```
SELECT email, 
   Avg(amount_paid) AS avg_paid, 
   Count(*)         AS no_times_booked 
FROM   bookings
GROUP  BY email
```

This gives me the email, average spend and number of times booked

my table looks like

```
email           | amount_paid | booking_date
email@email.com | 50.00       | 2010-01-13
email@email.com | 50.00       | 2010-01-13
email@email.com | 50.00       | 2010-01-13
```

How do I adjust my query to give me the average number of bookings per month?

so my results would look like the below, ultimately I am after one average number per user - if they only book once the following month their average would come down.

Or to put it another way, I am trying to label regular customers - one booking per month or above would be regular.

```
email           | avg_spend | number_bookings | avg_bookings_per_month
email@email.com | 50.00     | 3               | 3
```

Comment: `email@email.com | 50.00  | 2010-02-01` What about this entry will it be a second entry in the result.? I do you want to find the average in a month.?

Comment: Ultimately, I want just one average number for the entire history of the purchaser. If they only book once the next month then their average would come down.. Is that possible from one query?

Comment: I don’t think this is possible in a trivial way – because if they don’t book anything in a month, then you do not have an entry for that month in your database … so determining the overall number of month (which you would need to calculate an average) would be difficult.

Comment: Although you could try and calculate the number of month between their very first purchase and “now” somehow. (After all, from first until now is the only period to calculate the average over that makes sense.)

Comment: yer that makes, I am just trying to work out if they are a regular customer or not - one booking per month or above would be regular

Comment: infact what you said kind of clarifies what I am trying to do - work out an average number of bookings since they started and now

Comment: _“one booking per month or above would be regular”_ – I doubt this metric makes that much sense. Say I ordered 24 times in one month two years ago, and nothing any more since then – 24 orders divided by 24 month would still result in an average of 1, but I would be far from being a “regular” customer …

Comment: I’d say it would probably make more sense if you counted the month they made one (or more) orders in, and set that in relation to the number of month from first order until now … If I ordered first time half a year ago (6 month period), and there are four month that I ordered something in, then I could be considered a regular … whereas only 2 in 6 or 5 in 18 would mean not so regular.

Comment: Noted - almost need to work out number of bookings per month first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate the help, went with this

// If the number of times booked in last 12 months is equal too or above the unique no of months booked they booked in, they are a regular booker..

```
SELECT email, 
       Avg(amount_paid)                AS avg_paid, 
       Count(*)                        AS no_times_booked, 
       Count(DISTINCT( Month(added) )) AS unique_months 
FROM   bookings
WHERE  added >= Now() - INTERVAL 1 year 
GROUP  BY email
```

Comment: closest I could get - used php to add more logic

Answer (score 0):

You have most of it, but in order to get average bookings per month, you will need to nest your queries.  The inner-most query will be done based on a grouping of the email account AND the month/year of the booking (as to not confuse numbers of Jan 2014 and Jan 2015).

```
SELECT 
      PreAgg.email,
      sum( PreAgg.overallPaid ) as TotalPaid,
      sum( PreAgg.timesBooked ) as TimesBooked,
      sum( PreAgg.overallPaid ) / sum( PreAgg.timesBooked ) as OverallAvgPd,
      Avg( PreAgg.ThisMthYrAvgPd ) as AvgPerMthYr
   FROM   
      ( SELECT 
              email,
              year( booking_date ) as bkYear,
              month( booking_date ) as bkMth
              sum( amount_paid ) as overallPaid,
              count( * ) as timesBooked,
              avg( amount_paid ) as ThisMthYrAvgPd
           from 
              bookings
           group by
              email
              year( booking_date ),
              month( booking_date ) ) PreAgg
   GROUP  BY 
      PreAgg.email
```

However, this will get most of it, it wont get it all because we have no context to the time period the query represents.  The average per month/year is just of that.  But if you know the time period you are querying for ( ex: the entire year 2014), then you would need to compute the average per month DIVIDED BY 12 to get a more accurate per month rate.  Someone could travel 3 times in one month, then nothing for 6 months, then 2 more times.  Total of 5 times, but only 2 months worth of activity.  So it is up to you how YOU intend to quantify there "regular" guest/visitor status.  If its the 2 months that had bookings out of 12 vs total of 5 bookings out of 12 months gives totally different fractional answers.

Answer (score 0):

test with your query

```
      SELECT
YEAR(booking_date) AS YEAR,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 1 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/31 
ELSE 0 END JAN,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 2 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/28 
ELSE 0 END FEB,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 3 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/31 
ELSE 0 END MARCH,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 4 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/30 
ELSE 0 END APRL,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 5 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/31 
ELSE 0 END MAY,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 6 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/30 
ELSE 0 END JUNE,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 7 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/31 
ELSE 0 END JULY,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 8 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/31 
ELSE 0 END AUG,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 9 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/30 
ELSE 0 END SEP,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 10 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/31 
ELSE 0 END OCTOBER,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 11 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/30 
ELSE 0 END NOV,
CASE 
   WHEN  MONTH(booking_date) = 12 
    THEN SUM(amount_paid)/31 
ELSE 0 END DECE

FROM bookings
WHERE  booking_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 YEAR 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: INTERVAL as per your concern here data will be grouped as per month and year